# It is possible to use SimpleXML for Android in commercial apps?

Tags: java, android, xml, simple-framework

Welcome all

It is possible to use SimpleXML for android in commercial apps? THis is the website: http://simple.sourceforge.net/

I'm checking the documentation but my english skills are not too munch good. I didn't understand what i should do to use SimpleXML in commercial apps

I must put a textview with "This app has used SimpleXML" in some part of the app? it is possible to avoid it? It is a commercial app for a client, i need to avoid putting these kind of text on the app. I can put "This app has used SimpleXML" in my developer website on the info of this app, but not on the app, it is safe and legal to do it this way?

Wich restrictions i must complain to use this library into a commercial app?

thanks

Comment: If that library works in Android then its possible. It may or may not be legal though, which is what I suspect you are asking. However, you cannot get legal questions answered here, you need to talk to your attorney.

Comment: Yes you can, it is free to use and or modify for commercial purpose. It uses the Apache license.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just read through the details of the license of SimpleXML and can confirm that, yes, you can use the library in a commercial application.

You do not need to include a message in the application indicating that you are using that library - but there are a few things you need to do to comply with the license:

1. If you include the source code in your project, then you need to keep all comments in that source code, including the one pertaining to the license
2. If you give your client some sort of a document with the completed app describing the app, then that document needs to contain a note indicating that you are using SimpleXML.  If you do not provide your client with such a document, then you need to include a comment in your source code stating that you're using this library and include the link/attribution.

Other than that, you can use it as will.

Comment: Are you 100% sure about this? 100%? i can't find that in the license

Comment: And what about this? If a NOTICE text file is included as part of the distribution of the original work, then derivative works must include a readable copy of these notices (again, excluding notices not pertaining to any part of the derivative work), in at least one of three places: within a NOTICE text file distributed as part of the derivative works, within the source form or documentation, or within a display generated by the derivative works (wherever such third-party notices normally appear)

Comment: The file i'm using is a .JAR library file, but the zip file includes a LICENSE.txt file ¿what should i do?

Comment: @AndroidUser99 The part you indicated is what I stated in my point (2). If you're including a LICENSE file in your distribution, then you may put a paragraph of text at the bottom of it, stating that the application uses SimpleXML library provided by ... and include a link to it.  I believe this should be sufficient.

Comment: no no, i'm not including a license file! (but the zip with the .jar library i'm using for Simplexml does) it is a commercial app for a client, it is only a .apk file that will be bought at market :S

Comment: @AndroidUser99: that's fine.  Just include the simplexml jar file.  It's not a problem that it has the license included into itself.  It won't be visible from inside your app downloaded from the market.

Comment: are you 100% sure? i hope this is right, if not i can have huge troubles :S

Comment: I am quite sure, however if you are still in doubt, just email the authors of the simplexml library and ask them.

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can use XML there is no problem at all.